# Flutter front-end page onto page design

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, frontend

I have a frontend design issue: such as below design when I want to open a new page in my home page I want to show it just like that. New page onto my existent page(blurry background). Is there any simple way in Flutter for this issue? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you can try with dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Got it from here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html